# Drawing Polar Curves in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw the curve

```
r^2=4 \cos 2\theta
```

in LaTeX

I know how to draw `$r=4 \cos \theta$` using polar axis, but in the above problem it is `r^2`.

Comment: If you have any image (for sample purpose), please post it, to get clear picture of your requirement

Comment: What's about plotting $r=sqrt(4 \cos \theta)$ with positive AND negative sign?

Answer (score 8):

Run with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
         \psset{axesstyle=polar,plotpoints=1000,plotstyle=curve,unit=1.5}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=polar,linecolor=gray](2,360)
    \psplot[algebraic,polarplot,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=green]{-0.785}{0.785}{ 2*sqrt(cos(2*x)) } 
    \psplot[algebraic,polarplot,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=blue]{-0.785}{0.785}{ -2*sqrt(cos(2*x)) } 
\end{pspicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
    
\psset{axesstyle=polar,plotpoints=10000,plotstyle=curve}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
  \psaxes[axesstyle=polar,linecolor=gray](2,360)
  \psplot[algebraic,polarplot,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=green]{0}{20 Pi mul}{sqrt(4*cos(2*x))}
  \psplot[algebraic,polarplot,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red]{0}{20 Pi mul}{(4*cos(2*x))^0.3333}
\end{pspicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My sincere compliments.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution

Answer (score 2):

I have divided to get `r^2=4 \cos 2\theta` the domain in this way. It is very hard to plot directly `r^2=4 \cos 2\theta` in pgfplots:

```
  \addplot[domain=-45:45,samples=300, color=red] {2*sqrt(cos(2*x))};
  \addplot[domain=135:225,samples=300, color=red] {2*sqrt(cos(2*x))};
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
                     tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
                 }}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{polaraxis}[]
    \addplot[domain=-45:45,samples=300, color=red] {2*sqrt(cos(2*x))};
      \addplot[domain=135:225,samples=300, color=red] {2*sqrt(cos(2*x))};
  \end{polaraxis}

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what about if we have to draw $r^3=4\cos 2\theta$.

Comment: @InspireMaths I would make the cube root of the quantity 4\cos 2\theta.

Comment: @Sebastiano, `pgfplots` produced incorrect result, see how it should be https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=r%5E2%3D4cos%282theta%29 Can this be fixed?

Comment: @AndreyL. Yes, I have seen :-(. I have now no idea.

Comment: @AndreyL. It is the formula that generate the graph of a lemniscate r^2=4 \cos 2\theta

Comment: @AndreyL. Now it is correct. I have read the manual.